# "a half century" vs. "half a century"

Tags: phrases, differences, word-order, time, indefinite-articles

What is the difference between "a half century" and "half a century"? Is there a specific time when each phrase should be used, or is it simply a matter of preference?

Comment: The phrases are equivalent.  The second, "half a century," is actually a very common but ungrammatical diminutive of the phrase "half of a century."  The first ("a half century") is what you would expect to see in written English.  The second, in colloquial spoken English.  If possible, use the first, "a half century."

Comment: @JBH Do you use 'I'll be a half hour' rather than 'I'll be half an hour'? [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+half+an+hour%2Cbe+a+half+hour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20half%20an%20hour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20a%20half%20hour%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that about 80% of people prefer the latter. Grammar isn't static, and if you're going to claim that 'half an hour' and 'half a century' aren't acceptable, you need to post some supporting evidence from a credible source. // 'Half an hour' is idiomatic.

Comment: I have to agree with Edwin Ashworth, at least for the most part. I've seen both uses rather often, so I was simply wondering which is *most* acceptable. New question to add onto my previous ones: Is there any real proof that one is "more" correct than the other?

Comment: Actually, @EdwinAshworth, I do use "I'll be a half hour," but that's beside the point.  The OP didn't ask about it and It's been a while since I've heard anyone say "I'll be half a century" or "I'll be a half century."  Since you're claiming I need support, why don't you pony up and provide support that I'm wrong?

Comment: I also did ask if there is a specific time I should use these phrases. @JBH

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't what Ed was talking about.  He was using the half-hour constructs to demonstrate a point, not to express an answer to your question.  I apologize that you've been caught up in the crossfire of a small spat between us.  I hope you will forgive us.

Comment: @JBH << _half an hour_ noun: a period of 30 minutes _I'll be back in half an hour_ >> [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/half-an-hour)] // << _half an hour_: 30 minutes _I waited for half an hour._ [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20an%20hour)]. Your turn to find an authority saying it's unacceptable.

Comment: @JBH << _half an hour_ noun: a period of 30 minutes _I'll be back in half an hour_ >> [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/half-an-hour)] // << _half an hour_: 30 minutes _I waited for half an hour._ [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20an%20hour)]. << _Her medical career spanned half a century._  / _For more than half a century, the reassuring tones of BBC newscasters have informed British television viewers about world events_ >> [[CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/century)].Your turn to find ...

Comment: an authority saying these are unacceptable. // There is actually a subclass of idioms that use unconventional grammar (like 'All of a sudden'; 'He led them a merry dance'; 'The bigger, the better'); they are called extragrammatical idioms, not ungrammatical idioms.

Comment: Related ELL questions: [Implication of “for a half year”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141479); [What is the difference between “a half walnut cake” and “half a walnut cake”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96336). Unfortunately, I can't find a related question on this site; but I think this is a good, on-topic question that should not be closed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, in reference to the OP's question, when I put "half a century" into Collins I get nothing.  It does like "half century."  Even more concerning, M-W doesn't accept "half a century" or "half century."  Neither collins nor M-W use "half a century" as an example for "century."  CED also doesn't like either phrase, but I do concede that it uses the phrase "half a century" in an example for the word "century."  A quick search does not reveal a positive rule, but finding an example once out of nine tries from the sources you used doesn't bode well.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I don't have the reputation to push this conversation into chat and it's long past time we did.  Can you affect that change?

Comment: You need to add some basic research. JBH has got me to do some (perhaps he or she will also now 'pony up' rather than just give what looks like an opinion). But actual examples from reasonable sources would be useful.

Comment: @JBH You won't find many examples of sentences containing 'twenty-seven-year old aardvark' either, but that doesn't constitute proof of unacceptability. The internet is littered with examples of 'half an hour' and 'half a century'. / You fail to explain why 'half a century' should be considered an 'ungrammatical diminutive of the phrase "half of a century" ' whereas 'half an hour' is a grammatical diminutive. Perhaps you prefer 'a half mo' to 'half a mo'.

Comment: Probably covered as comprehensively as is possible at  ["Half an hour" versus "half hour"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/half-an-hour-versus-half-hour), where "a half hour" is soon introduced.

Comment: A cricket innings of 50+ is almost always "a half century". I found a couple of uses of the other, but they were far outnumbered by phrases such as "the best innings in half a century". Otherwise I can't think of a scenario where they're not interchangeable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth to be fair, although collins and merriam have definitions of 'half an hour', neither defines 'half a century'. despite that, i agree that nothing is static. we make the rules based on our usage.

Comment: @oldboy Nor 'half a decade', 'half a millenium', or 'half an inch', I'd guess. These are free  combinations (like yellow bird, old tree). "_Half_, not _half of_, is used in the pattern _half a/an ..._ and is followed by a noun of measurement:

_It’s at least half a kilometre to those shops._ " [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/half)]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you mean a *a unit* of measurement, ya? i can think of other examples that dont follow that pattern e.g. 'i ate half a plate' or 'we mowed half the lawn'. ive noticed there seems to be a "movement" to or "trend" of omitting prepositions (e.g. 'of') and conjuctions (e.g. 'that') in colloquial speech/text, which allows such speech/text to be more concise, imo. personally, i dont necessarily view dictionaries as complete references, but more like a book of observations/examples to be used as a guideline. language is too dynamic for dictionaries to ever be that thorough

Comment: @oldboy The quote was from CED, not me. But 'lawn' can hardly be reasonably labelled a 'noun of measurement'. 'A shedload of' is usually termed a _fuzzy quantifier_. / Preposition deletion is well known, covered on ELU, though as you say progressive. / Of course dictionaries aren't ... can't be ... comprehensive. But they tend to be less error-prone and biased than even practised native speakers. They have usage panels, and researchers investigating usage patterns. All well educated.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (1) i dont know what CED and ELU are? (2) thats exactly my point; neither example that i provided follows the pattern you proposed. (3) definitely agree. however, the point i meant to make is that lots of ppl falsely presume that dictionaries are comprehensive references rather than, for a lack of better words, incomplete referencs or guidelines

Comment: And the point I'm making is that even so, they tend to be less error-prone and biased than even practised native speakers. They survey mixed samples and have largish usage panels to analyse the results, whereas individuals may wrongly presume what they're familiar with defines what is standard. // ELU is this site. CED can be worked out by comparing with OED, though I think Cambridge have dropped the 'English' now.